# Is there a way to open, save, and then close excel files in a directory in R?

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

Basically, there are a few excel reports that are emailed every morning to us. I download them directly to a specified drive then I wrangle them in R.

The thing is that I have to manually open each file and save them before running my script in R. If not this will happen:

[image]

When I go in and manually open and save the files and re-run my script. I get the correct results:
[image]

Firstly, do you guys know why this happens? and secondly, is there a function that will allow me to open these files and save them. I did try openxlsx. However, I still have to manually press the save button.

Here is the function I created to bring in the files:

```
store.FUN = function(x)
    {
       m = as.data.frame(read_excel(file))
       names(m) = c(1:length(m))
       m[1, 1] = str_sub(m[2, 1], 13)
       m = bind_rows((m)[1, ], subset(m, (m)[1] == "Total Income"))
       m[2, 1] = m[2, 2]
       m = m[-c(2)]
       return(m)
    }

district_1.stores = sapply(store.file, store.FUN, simplify=FALSE) %>% 
        bind_rows(.id = "Store ID")
```

Thanks!

Edit: So it looks like the cells are formulated:

[image]

[image]

But, if I do nothing and only save the file and go back to R to perform the script, the numbers pull in just fine.

Here is an example of the excel file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZqUZ.png)

Comment: "manually open each file" --> does that mean you open the excel file that's emailed to you in Excel, and save it to a new xlsx file? And this version reads into R correctly, but the version you receive does not?

Comment: Please show what code you used to open the file. There are a few different packages that help with excel files, and it's possible they might work differently with the example you're working with. Do you know what kind of computer/software is generating the excel files?

Comment: So quickbooks sends daily P&L's for a few of our stores. If I simply right click and save them into the drive without opening the file, R reads the values as zero's. However, If I open the file and just simply save it and re-run the script, R is able to read the values. To bring the files into R, I simply use read_excel.

Comment: Hmm, are the cells in the excel file a formula or just the actual values? Are these macro-enabled workbooks?

Comment: Here's a deep dive on different ways of opening excel files in R. Do any of these alternatives work better for you? https://lgreski.github.io/dsdepot/2020/06/13/reading-Excel-files.html. I think XLConnect or xlsx are more likely to be able to evaluate the formulas.

Comment: They are not macro enabled. But it looks like there are formulas.

Comment: openxlsx really should be able to pull files with formulas. Is there any way you could share one pf those original files that doesn‘t open correctly for you?

Comment: And the formula is lilely not the problem, because once you open/close your file, it still contains formulas and csn ve read in. So it sounds more like a header issue in the Excel file that the paclages can‘t solve, but disappears once you process the file in Excel itself.

Comment: @quel_barachi I meant if you can share the actual file, not an image. Otherwise it‘s impossible to test what‘s going on.

Comment: Maybe host it somewhere on dropbox or onedrive or any other preferred hosting service and provide the link here: note, it will be publicly accessible then, so maybe you can first go to quickbooks and create a copy of your account/details and then just put in fake numbers? Unless you are fine sharing the revenue figures of your company.

Comment: @deschen  https://1drv.ms/x/s!At2h9-hXeW7AiApc60e1YhTUbsyi?e=ZExBtK

Comment: This one works fine for me. What happens if you save this file and use this one: `test <- openxlsx::readWorkbook(file.choose())`. Does it work? Because I'm not sure if sharing the web excel file already fixes the issue (like your opening/closing the file). Ideally, you could really upload the xls file somewhere, so that I can just download it.

Comment: So then it's probably something on your machine, because for me the file processes just fine. Do you have the latest R/Rstudio version and package updates?

Comment: I do. I have the latest version as well as 3.5. Also, I created a python script to loop through the workbooks and save them which works perfectly. However, Im not a huge fan of workflows being different in any way. I did attempt to use the openXL function but im not sure if its possible to utilize the function in such a way that it opens, saves, and closes.

Comment: The zip file seems to be not there anymore?

Comment: ok, with the zip file, I can at least confirm the issue, I get all zeros.

Comment: OK, at this point I unfortunately don't have a solution. However, what I'd suggest is to reach out to e.g. the developer from the openxlsx package and file an issue here: https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx The developer is very responsive and I had an openxlsx issue in the past that he was able to solve. I'm not saying that the behaviour is an openxlsx issue (since you also have it with the readr package), but it might still be an issue that he can fix in his package.

Comment: Something similar was happening to Excel files I was getting from SQLDeveloper, but in my case the file was read into R as one long column.  I had to do something similar: open the file and save under a different name, then openxlsx and R had no problem with the new file.  I wonder if the apps we use are adding something to the Excel file that doesn't get saved when we open it and save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the time to post the issue on github for `openxlsx`.

Tl;dr: it's not a bug, it's a built-in "problem" when importing from/exporting to Excel and is true for all such packages. The developer suggests exactly what the TO did in case Excel sheets contain formula: open the file in Excel first, save it and only then import it into R. Which doesn't answer the TO's question (which was how to open and save an Excel file automatically through R), but I'm posting this answer nonetheless, because it adds some helpful context.

https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues/261 and https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues/188#issuecomment-832591241

Answer (score 0):

Actually just found that I can use the "reticulate" package in R to run a python module for this purpose.

Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: Although this isn‘t necessarily a solution. It‘s avoiding an existing problem/bug.